# indeed website webscraping pagination issue

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am stuck on page navigation when webscraping indeed. My page navigation has been working fine but it stopped a week back and I can not seem to fix it. It just goes from page 1 to 2 in a loop, therefore in a 6 page search it will visit page 1 + 2, three time each.

I have tried several methods, all just go from page 1 to 2 and then back to 1 again. Could someone please advise what the correct class or querySelector is?

[Indeed](https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=manager&l=london)

**I was using this**

```
Do
    If pageNumber >=6 Then Exit Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("np")(0) ' CLICK TO NEXT PAGE

    If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
        nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
   
   Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
    Loop
```

I have since tried this, but can not seem to work it out

```
Do
  If pageNumber >=6  Then Exit Do
        Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("pagination-list")(0)
       'Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("pagination")(0)
  If Not nextPageElement Is Nothing Then
         nextPageElement.document.querySelector(".np").Click
        'nextPageElement.document.querySelector(".pn").Click
        'nextPageElement.document.querySelector("span.pn").Click
        'nextPageElement.document.querySelector("span.np").Click
          Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
        Else:
            Exit Do
        End If

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
    Loop
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
  <div class="pagination" onmousedown="pclk(event);">
    <ul class="pagination-list">
      <li><b aria-current="true" aria-label="1" tabindex="0">1</b></li>
      <li>
        <a href="/jobs?q=manager&amp;l=london&amp;start=10" aria-label="2" data-pp="gQAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABpUM3WgA3AQAHXaNdLSF435uhaW440sBEPpyo6wu9yyY2dv2zPlwOkia1_Ad0YcnE3oC5V5SAQfMv9shHtgAA" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);" rel="nofollow"><span class="pn">2</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/jobs?q=manager&amp;l=london&amp;start=20" aria-label="3" data-pp="gQAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABpUM3WgBeAQEBCG4JQk5YFZSUl7gsr035q39vtzDHJitYqr4vM2MFHgSufSgx4aWdnXw91UygifbITTf_9Xd-zeBWg6A2eTj9AkpYnhX-rcAjN1nrUkthXyccybLf4M72Myp_oAAA" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"
          rel="nofollow"><span class="pn">3</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="/jobs?q=manager&amp;l=london&amp;start=30" aria-label="4" data-pp="gQAtAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABpUM3WgCCAQMBCBIHEAgKK3TbOCxrwjMPxwTV6_j9fNaHMo3xNxBWr7N7iCbTP36N-nxYL04iAaq5_diz3DVQ63zhssHzded33JzRuIfyx9aiyFO2ElmBhWcblWNGlmhwv7P7-3rovVi7CVDOHjCKDCVg45A442qbMJ5Wo9JtMKsCponthuH3GQAA"
          onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);" rel="nofollow"><span class="pn">4</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="/jobs?q=manager&amp;l=london&amp;start=40" aria-label="5" data-pp="gQA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABpUM3WgChAQIBCBISRVBBqQZzCe6zv5ptH6EOR3ZxgRqrJvxsJggbwhKYOoxC_WmDgzvp-t1_I5-ajTgabdUP917NrwmP_ZTSJKw7Qsu2h2XODIZnEGpR4EUkRNB8BJX7y01xkWMfbFMYqgQQyGS_4mI9NrbWaont2mhvbhw4_6obi9V3Dq16okhKL7ATYpwifpNN_iYSoSsoyTM2DFqJO76sH6r8Cg4AAA"
          onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);" rel="nofollow"><span class="pn">5</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="/jobs?q=manager&amp;l=london&amp;start=10&amp;pp=gQAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABpUM3WgA3AQAHXaNdLSF435uhaW440sBEPpyo6wu9yyY2dv2zPlwOkia1_Ad0YcnE3oC5V5SAQfMv9shHtgAA" aria-label="Next" data-pp="gQAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABpUM3WgA3AQAHXaNdLSF435uhaW440sBEPpyo6wu9yyY2dv2zPlwOkia1_Ad0YcnE3oC5V5SAQfMv9shHtgAA"
          onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);" rel="nofollow">
          <span class="pn">
          <span class="np">
          <svg width="24" height="24" fill="none"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6-6-6z" fill="#2D2D2D"></path>
          </svg></span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As always thanks in advance

###############   UPDATE TODAY THUR 20TH MAY  #####################

The website is called [Indeed](https://uk.indeed.com/) This is the uk version, I did not post this link as it only has the job search page, which does not have the page pagination on it. This link [New Link](https://uk.indeed.com/manager-jobs-in-london) is when the search criteria has been found and it is this page that has the page pagination on it, hence why i posted it in my first post.

Thanks for having a look

##################   update 22/5/20201 ###########################

Also posted here [Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/page-navigation-on-indeed-website.1171729/)

Comment: Can we please have the actual url?

Comment: QHarr, please see my edit above in my post, which is regarding your question

Comment: I am really stuck on this and can not work it, I would appreciate if someone could advise on the correct class or querySelector. As always thanks in advance